# Lucence index into memcache

Tags: java, search, lucene, search-engine

Hi is there any way to store indexed data from lucence into memcache?

I have a arraylist and added that list datas into a file with indexed data using lucence index writer . Is it possible to store the same in memcache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need code to make memcache look like a directory.